# How can a BAT script find the partition number of %systemdrive%

Tags: partition, batch-file, grub

I am trying to write a BAT script to produce a grub4dos menu.lst file.

A boot entry in the  menu.lst file typically contains a line like:

```
root (hdx,y)
```

where x is the hard disk number(first disk hd0) and y is the partition number on the disk  (first partition is 0). How can I find the disk and partition numbers of %systemdrive% ?

The script will be running under Windows Vista or 7.

Answer (score 1):

```
WMIC LogicalDisk GET param1, param2 (etc.)
```

I'm not sure there is a partition number as such. A list of the WMI classes (e.g. LogicalDisk) that you can inspect is here: [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa394084(v=vs.85).aspx)

If you're using Windows 7 the Powershell alternative is:

```
Get-WmiObject Win32_LogicalDisk | Where {$_.DriveType -eq "3"} | Select param1, param2
```

EDIT: There is a class for specific partitions: Win32_DiskPartition this does contain an `Index` property. The `Name` property will give you both the disk and partition id (but you will have to parse it).